# Copy Linked List to Another List?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, copy, duplicates

I need help in linked list, to make a function for copy a list to another list

I code with Visual Studio 2012. Here is my code and the error that I get:

ERROR:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0111544F in linked list.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.

Could someone please tell me what's the mistake and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
};

void PrintList (node *C)
{  
    node *P;
    cout<<"Node content = (";
    P = C;
    while(P!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<P->info;
        P = P->next;
        if(P != NULL) 
            cout<<",";       
    }
    cout<<")"<<endl;
}

void copylist (node *Y, node **Z)
{
    node *P, *Q;
    int temp;
    if (Y==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"the list is empty"<<endl;
        *Z=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        P=Y;
        Q=*Z;
        while (P->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=P->info;
            Q->info=temp;
            P=P->next;
            Q=Q->next;
        }
    }
}

void insertnode (int *A, node **Q)
{
    node *N, *P;

    N=new node;
    N->info=*A;
    N->next=NULL;

    if(*Q==NULL)
        *Q=N;
    else
    {
        P=*Q;

        while (P->next!=NULL)
            P=P->next;

        P->next=N;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    node *z;
    node *duplicate;
    z=NULL;
    duplicate=new node;
    int e;
    int i;
    int *temp;
    temp=new int;

    cout<<"the number of element : ";
    cin>>e;

    cout<<" LIST Z CONTENT : " <<endl;
    PrintList (z);

    for (i=0;i<e;i++)
    {
        cin>>*temp;
        insertnode(temp, &z);
    }

    copylist(z,&duplicate);

    cout<<" DUPLICATE LIST CONTENT : "<<endl;
    PrintList(duplicate);
}
```

Comment: Once a few missing elements are added, [your code works](http://rextester.com/VDSX22970). The problem must lie in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. In the current example the list to be copied is empty so nothing's done.

Comment: @jimmymsz There are a lot of problems with this code. I presume this is not <tag>homework</tag> because it's not tagged. In which case it may be easier for you to start out by just using a [`list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and coming back to understand the theory behind it when you understand C++ a bit better.

Comment: @jimmymsz: Thanks for adding mode code. Was your problem solved?

Comment: @all,
sorry for late reply,
thanks for all to answering my question. problem already solved..

Comment: Please do not add comments explaining why you edited into the text (EDIT: etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that in main function, you are trying to print an empty list with the following code:

```
cout<<" LIST Z CONTENT : " <<endl;
PrintList (z);
```

So, you may want to modify your print function as:

```
void PrintList(node *C)
{
    if (C == NULL) return; // return if the list is empty or print out a message
    node *P = C;
    cout << "Node content = (";

    while (P != NULL)
    {
        cout << P->info;
        P = P->next;
        if (P != NULL)
            cout << ",";
    }
    cout << ")" << endl;
}
```

And in your copy function, you forgot to create new node and keep the link to it during the copy process. Here is the code that would work:

```
void copylist(node *Y, node **Z)
{
    if (Y == NULL)
    {
        cout << "the list is empty" << endl;
        *Z = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node*P = Y;
        node *Q = NULL;

        while (P != NULL)
        {
            node* newNode = new node; // first create a node (allocate memory)
            newNode->info = P->info; // then fill the info
            newNode->next = NULL;
            if (Q == NULL)
            {
                Q = newNode;
                *Z = Q;
            }
            else
            {
                Q->next = newNode;
                Q = Q->next;
            }
            P = P->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, your main function does not return anything!! You may want to add

```
return 0;
```

at the end.

Try replacing your main function with:

```
int main()
{
    node *z = NULL;
    node *duplicate = NULL;

    int e;
    cout << "The number of elements : ";
    cin >> e;

    cout << "enter elements with a space between them : ";
    while (e--)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        insertnode(temp, &z);
    }

    cout << " LIST Z CONTENT : " << endl;
    PrintList(z);

    copylist(z, &duplicate);

    cout << " DUPLICATE LIST CONTENT : " << endl;
    PrintList(duplicate);

    cin >> e;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, for copying a list to another, you can call the `insertnode` function in a loop for adding all the data of the original list to the new list in a loop. This will make your copy function even shorter.

For more information about Linked Lists:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**You can't copy a list without allocating memory.**

You have an access violation cause you're not creating **new** nodes in your destination list when you copy, but rely on whatever (corrupt pointer) is in `next` when you use a `node`.
Other than that you have a small memory leak.

Note the lines with comments:

```
void copylist (node *Y, node **Z)
{
    node *P, *Q;
    if (Y==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"the list is empty"<<endl;
        //*Z=NULL;        // memory leak! lost pointer of caller!
    }
    else
    {
        P=Y;
        Q=*Z;
        while (P->next!=NULL)
        {
            Q->info = P->info;
            P=P->next;
            Q->next = new node();      // missing allocation!
            Q = Q->next;
        }
        Q->next = null;                // close new list.
    }
}
```